# Constantinople hard fork and Ethereum based tokens

Tags: tokens, exchanges, hardforks, constantinople

I have a question: Do we have to deposit all of our Ethereum tokens into some exchange before the Constantinople hard fork, otherwise our tokens will become worthless? Or we can leave our tokens in our ETH wallets as we did until now? This hard fork is very confusing, it makes people fear they will lose their tokens or their tokens value...

Answer (score 2):

Exactly the opposite, take your ether to *your* wallet. By *your wallet*, I mean a wallet that you are the only person who knows the private key. If you don't do this and leave your ether, say in an exchange, then it's up to that exchange to what happens your forked ethers.

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum token have a property: they never (never!) came out of the smart contract which manage them.

They are not in your wallet nor in some exchange nor whatever. What you have in your wallet is the record of the answer from the smart contract when you asked: “giving I have this 0x... address, what token of your kind are accounted to me?”. The smart contract look in its internal records and say to you: 1500 are yours. The wallet record this and show it to you.

If you loose the wallet, they are still there for you. It is sufficient to give to a new wallet your account and the address of the token smart contract and voila, they are in it again.

Nothing more, nothing less.

When you “transfer” you simply modify the token smart contract accounting in order to diminish one account balance and increase one other account balance. You do not transfer any token!

Your wallet simply sync with the smart contract and give you the updated balance as it is in the smart contract storage.

Nothing more, nothing less.

So, coming to your question, what is registered in blockchain before any fork shall be invariably present after the fork, and the smart contract will give you again your balance if queried by your wallet or by you.

Maintain your password and so on in a safe place and relax: you are not required to do something. All will be ok.